# What is the SQL Server equivalent of EXECUTE IMMEDIATE INTO in Oracle

Tags: oracle11g, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql

What is the SQL Server equivalent of `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE INTO` in Oracle?

E.g.

```
DECLARE QRY varchar(100);

val int;

BEGIN

QRY:='select count(*) from production.product';

**EXECUTE IMMEDIATE** QRY **into** val;

dbms_output.put_line(val);

END;

/
```

Comment: I want a way by which I can store the value of total row count returned from select statement.

Comment: My purpose is to store value returned from a dynamic query into a given variable. I just gave an e.g. for your quick understanding. please help me on this.

Comment: Let's say, in place of total no. of rows I want to store value of SUM of a given column into a variable. Then what should be my code. Just replace the query like, QRY:=select sum(quantity) from production.product

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't set a scalar variable to the results of a dynamic query, but you can insert the results into a table variable. This works.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (RowCnt INT NULL);

DECLARE
   @QRY varchar(100);

BEGIN

  SET @QRY = 'select <Aggregate Function> from tableName'; --Builds the dynamic query

  INSERT @tbl
    (
      RowCnt
    )
  EXECUTE(@QRY); --Executes the query

  SELECT 
    * 
  FROM @tbl;

END;
```

Comment: Thank you Sir. You are very helpful. It all works and I have verified my answer

Comment: Excellent! I'm glad to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

T-SQL equivalent for EXECUTE IMMEDIATE is **Dynamic Sql**.

```
DECLARE @intCount int
EXECUTE sp_executesql N'select @intCount=count(*) from product', N'@intCount int output', @intCount output;
Print(@intCount)
```

Alternatively, you can use

```
DECLARE @intCount2 int
SELECT @intCount2 = count(*) from product
```

Comment: You are not storing the value of total row count returned. That is my purpose and the purpose of EXECUTE IMMEDIATE INTO

Comment: I want a way by which I can store the value of total row count returned from select statement.

Comment: You are not executing it dynamically. I want to execute it dynamically and store it's value in a variable. Please take some other option like sum of a given column in a table and store it in a variable.